# Execute pure query in Zend 1 with dynamic limit and offset

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to execute a pure query in Zend 1 with limit and offset which are dynamic. Eg: Query is static but I need to pass limit and offset dynamically to generate pagination.

I tried using `Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()->query()->fetchAll($queryString),` but don't know how to add limit and offset. can anybody tell the right syntax.

Answer (score 1):

If `$queryString` is a `string`, you can try this:

```
// $begin = your dynamic value
// $end   = your dynamic value
$queryString .= " LIMIT $begin, $end ";
```

If `$queryString` is a `Zend_Db_Select`, you can try this:

```
// $begin = your dynamic value
// $end   = your dynamic value
$queryString->limit($begin, $end );
```

The doc about [limit](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/fr/zend.db.select.html#zend.db.select.building.limit).